# What is the difference between <Scope>test</scope> and <Scope>Compile</Scope>?

Tags: maven

I'm using the following dependency, what is the affect that i get, if i change the scope to compile?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This question should be tagged witn maven, not sql-server. Please read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: I gone through your link, but i'm not seeing any change in the project if i do shift the scope element to test and compile vise versa. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dependency with test scope will not be included in the final build. Lets say you are building a war file and you wrote some junit tests. Per maven convention, your tests resides in src/main/test folder. In your pom.xml you include junit dependency with test scope. When you run `mvn package` goal, your test will be executed. During the test phase, maven uses the junit jar and compiles the test classes but the junit jar will not be included in the final war file. If you change junit scope to compile, then the junit dependency will be available during testing phase and also it will be included in the final war file.

Comment: Thank you Ramu! Now i understand the clear picture.